# Que estoy haciendo Mal en este Query ? | SQL

Tags: sql

Buen Dia colegas quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal en este Query:

```
  ALTER  PROCEDURE  SPQ_Estado_Situacion               
@FechaNuevoFormato1 nvarchar(MAX),          
@FechaNuevoFormato2 nvarchar(MAX)          
AS          
 BEGIN   
   
DECLARE  @TABLA AS TABLE  
(  
    Cuenta        VARCHAR(50),   
    Nombre        VARCHAR(100),   
    Monto         FLOAT,   
    Fecha         DATE,   
    Clasificación VARCHAR(100)  
);  
  
  
INSERT INTO @TABLA(Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación)          
SELECT Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación From Balanzas   
  
SET LANGUAGE 'Spanish'  
 
DECLARE @Fecha1 datetime ,@Fecha2 datetime ;  
 
--Mostrar los montos en dos columnas de fechas.  
SELECT MAX(Cuenta)as Cuenta,Clasificación,  
    SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= @FechaNuevoFormato1 AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @FechaNuevoFormato1) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFecha1,  
    SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= @FechaNuevoFormato2 AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @FechaNuevoFormato2) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFecha2  
FROM @TABLA where Clasificación  IN ('Caja y bancos','Cuentas por cobrar','Inventario','Impuestos a favor','Deudores Diversos','Anticipo a Proveedores','IVA Acreditable','Otros Activos')   
GROUP BY Clasificación ORDER BY Cuenta;  
  
 END
```

El problema es que las sumas me los trae en `0` y realmente la los datos si tiene numero para ser sumados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecuto el store asi :  `EXEC SPQ_Estado_Situacion  '2025-01-01 00:00:00.000' ,'2025-01-01 00:00:00.000'`

espero que me puedan ayudar ,gracias

Comment: Cambia el tipo de @FechaNuevoFormato1 y @FechaNuevoFormato2 
 de nvarchar(MAX) a `DateTime `. El parámetro de fecha se lo puedes pasar sin especificar minutos, etc. Por ejemplo `EXEC SPQ_Estado_Situacion  '2025-01-01', '2025-01-01'`

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @RogerTorné pero ya lo intente y no funciona ,de hecho solo funciona con ciertas fechas pero los que quiero no los suma ,los retorna en 0

Comment: "Castea" `@FechaNuevoFormato1` y `@FechaNuevoFormato2` a un `DATE` siempre que lo compares  con `Fecha`, por ejemplo `Fecha >= CONVERT(DA_tE, @FechaNuevoFormato1) AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATE, @FechaNuevoFormato1))` esto seguramente o hace que funcione bien o te demuestre algún problema en el dato del filtro

Comment: Tomando los datos que muestras, sí me arroja el resultado esperado. Esto parece ser un error de datos.